# Are activation records consecutive in memory?

Tags: compiler-construction, operating-system, programming-languages

Are activation records laid out contiguously in memory? If yes, why?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is... it depends. In many programming languages (such as C or C++), it's implementation-defined whether they're laid out consecutively in memory, but they usually are. This is because it's super fast to allocate activation records on the stack by having a single stack pointer and just incrementing or decrementing it to allocate/deallocate memory. However, there's no guarantee that the language will do this.

In other languages - especially ones that support closures - activation records are not laid out contiguously because the memory for the activation record may need to be saved as part of a closure. In that case, memory is not necessarily allocated and deallocated in a pattern that follows a stack, so the activation records are often scattered throughout memory. Additionally, languages with coroutines or generators (such as Python) cannot necessarily store activation records consecutively in a stack because the order in which functions are active and the order in which they finish doesn't obey the last-in/first-out pattern you need for a stack.

Comment: Can you please explain what did you mean by "languages that support closures"? I need an example, maybe even a link.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I taught a compilers class one time and have [some slides on this](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1128/lectures/11/Slides11.pdf) if you'd like to check them out!

Comment: @templatetypedef But we can maintain explicit links to next/previous records in an Activation Record and modify the stack pointer using them when allocating/deallocating memory. Why having them contiguous is faster then?

Comment: @templatetypedef - Thanks Mr. Scwarz, that really helped. :)

Comment: @snehasawlani How familiar are you with the implementation of the function stack on most systems versus the heap? The stack is significantly faster than the heap (often, it takes one assembly instruction to allocate or deallocate memory on the stack), which is why allocating activation records there is so fast.

Comment: @templatetypedef I see what you are saying. I guess I was not clear in asking my question. What I really want to know is does the OS always assign a contiguous block of memory to the program for implementing the run time stack? For example, is it possible that OS combined different blocks of free memory and provide it to the program as a Linked List which the program can then use as a stack?
I do agree with the part that having activation records as a stack is more efficient. All I want to know is do the nodes of that stack need to be  actually laid out consecutively in memory?

Comment: @snehasawlani Ah, I see what you're asking. The answer is no - there's no requirement that everything be laid out in contiguous memory. The OS doesn't *have* to set up a stack and heap, and programs don't *have* to use the given runtime stack. However, since it's substantially more efficient for programs to take advantage of this, in places where it's possible, programs usually do this.

Comment: @templatetypedef What do you mean by "this"  in "it's substantially more efficient for programs to take advantage of this".  Having contiguous memory? Or having OS set up a stack and heap for programs?